# Python 3.7.3 IDLE can't find kivy module

Tags: python, kivy

I just installed the Kivy module and I went to make sure it was working properly by simply entering `import kivy` only to receive this error:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivy'`

I know that it installed it but I'm not sure why I can't use it. I used pip installer. The main file and its dependencies all installed to this directory:

`C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages`

Anyone know how I can get it to import the kivy module properly (kinda a newbie :/)?

Comment: mmmm Python **3.7.3** IDLE .... and  ...\Python **36** \? It seems that you have installed kivy in python3.6 but you want to use it in IDLE of python3.7. That makes no sense.

Comment: Let me guess, the Python installation you're using to execute the program isn't the same as the one where the package was installed? As an aside, please always share the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty, thanks to eyllanesc it's solved. The module had installed to Python 3.6 while I was using 3.7 since I had both versions on my PC. I simply uninstalled 3.6 since I didn't need it and then went back through the process of installing kivy and it all works now.